# Power Apps - Rich Text Editor in form: Randomly unable to view/edit (possible height issue)

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps, rich-text-editor

I'm having an issue with the **Rich Text Editor** displaying in a custom Power Apps form I created thru/for SharePoint Online.  Below are the details

---

#### Problem

Somewhat randomly, The **Rich Text Editor** control loads incorrectly.  It appears that the **Height** is displaying incorrectly, regardless of the FormMode (New, Edit, or View). The user is unable to view/edit any text to the control.

Example:

[image: Rich Text Editor - Incorrect]

---

### Expected Behavior

FormMode.New

[image]

FormMode.Edit & FormMode.View

[image]

---

### Workaround

The only workaround we have at the moment is to refresh (F5) the webpage, but this doesn't always fix the issue.  Some users refresh 20 - 30 times before the form is fully visible.

---

### Steps to Reproduce

The issue is random, so it's difficult to reproduce when you want it to happen.  Below are steps to create the form in SharePoint & Power Apps.

1. In [SharePoint Online](https://www.office.com/launch/sharepoint), create a list with a column for **Enhanced rich text (Rich text with pictures, tables, and hyperlinks)**

[image: List column settings for rich text]

2. List Settings  Form Settings: Enable the custom form in PowerApps option

[image: Enable custom form in PowerApps]

3. List Settings  Form Settings: Select the **Modify form in PowerApps link.

[image: edit form in PowerApps]

4. If the default control is not a **Rich Text Editor**, you may need to modify it.
5. Width = 1124
6. Height = 158
7. Save & Publish the PowerApps form.
8. Select +New in the SharePoint list to display the custom form.

Results

See the problem section above.  Keep in mind, this is random.

---

### What I've Tried

1. I found a post in the Power Apps Community for [Rich Text Editor Not displaying text input section](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Rich-Text-Editor-Not-displaying-text-input-section/td-p/169345).  Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get this to work.  Also, the post suggests it would be fixed toon and that was back in 2018, so I wouldn't expect to still see the issue.
2. I noticed the rich text box had a larger height value than it's parent, but adjusting that didn't fix the issue.

---

Any assistance would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The dimensions of the rich text field seems improbable large... 1024x158... Doesnt it get cut off? I would take a look at the data in the field when there is a reported issue. Perhaps its a combo of the dimensions of the field in the app and its content in some cases?

Comment: @RuneBH the issue occurs with new list items containing no data as well as existing items.